# How to build a struct with a pointer as one of its fields and pass it to c++ from python?

Tags: c++, python-2.7, ctypes

I'm trying to build a struct in python(ctypes) and pass it on to a C++ file,
I'm trying to do something like this:

**Python**

```
class Astruct(Structure):
        _fields_ = ("fieldA",c_int) , ("fieldB", (pointer_of(some_object)) * 5)
```

**C++**

```
struct Astruct{
private:
    int fieldA[52] = {0};
    some_object *fieldB[2];
    ....
```

How do i do this?

Thanks

Comment: 'fieldB' is supposed to be an array of pointers.

Comment: Ok, that worked, but now when I try to enter a value I get an error:
**The code**
`Astruct.fieldB[0] = POINTER(some_object)`
The error:
`TypeError: must be a ctypes type`

Comment: I did initialize it I don't no why but it worked if I use lower case eg: `pointer(some_object)`